# How can I update a table using a Qthread?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

In my real application, I am trying to update a qtablewidget with a lot of data. The problem is that the table update takes a while and the gui is practically frozen while it's doing it. I wrote a very small snippet of what I am basically trying to do. 
I would like to do the same thing, but the update done via a Qthread because that would help keep the gui active, which I'm not sure on how to do yet. I already tried `QtGui.qApp.processEvents()` but it's still too laggy that's why I need a thread. Please advise.

Here's is a small example of what i am trying to do.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class TryingStuff(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TryingStuff, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("Trying stuff")
        self.doJob = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.closebutton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.closebutton = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.closebutton.setText('Close')
        self.closebutton.setMaximumWidth(150)
        self.closebutton.clicked.connect(self.close)
        self.doJob.setText("do job")
        self.doJob.setMaximumWidth(100)
        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.setUpTable(self.table)
        self.doJob.clicked.connect(lambda: self.putStuffInA(self.table))
        self.table.verticalHeader().hide()
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.doJob, 0,  QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.table)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.closebutton, 0, QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
        # self.connect(self.worker, QtCore.SIGNAL("updateTable(QString)"), self.updateTable)


    def setUpTable(self, table):
        table.setColumnCount(2)
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Col 1"))
        table.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem("Col 2"))

        table.setMinimumWidth(500)
        header = table.horizontalHeader()
        header.setResizeMode(1, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        #header.setResizeMode(2, QtGui.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        table.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True)

    def putStuffInA(self, table):
        a = 0
        lista =[]
        while a < 10:
            print a
            lista.append(a)
            a += 1
        table.setRowCount(len(lista))
        self.populateTable(lista, table)

    def populateTable(self, lista, table):
        try:
            for i in lista:
                desc = QtGui.QTableWidgetItem()
                buttonA = QtGui.QPushButton()
                #buttonA.clicked.connect(self.printing(i))
                buttonA.setText("A")
                desc.setText(str(i))
                table.setItem(i, 0, desc)
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
                table.setCellWidget(i, 1, buttonA)
                QtGui.qApp.processEvents()
        except Exception:
            pass

    def printing(self, i):
        print i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    k = TryingStuff()
    k.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Are you sure that "... the table update takes a while ..." ? I guess just calculating data for the table takes a while? Then you could just create a `QThread`, let it calculate the data and once it is done, send a signal to the application and it will just fill the data into the table (which should be fast). But if you really want the `QThread` to fill the table, it might be pain.

Comment: Yeah, the part about sending the signal to fill the table with data is where I'm confused. And also what I need to do. It does take a while.

Answer (score 0):

This might help you to get started, if it won't help, let me know :) Basically, you create a `Worker`, which will do the work for you in `QThread`. When you click `doJob` button, it will call method of your `Worker` (note if you need to set some parameters for this computation, do it **before** the call). Once the computation is finished, it will emit the signal `computationFinished` back to `TryingStuff` object. Via connecting this signal to `putStuffInA` method you can fill the table with data.

```
class MyWorker(QtCore.QObject):
    computationFinished = QtCore.pyqtSignal() # emited when simulations is finished

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self, parent)

        self.dataForTable = []
        # or some other needed attributes

        self.TheWorker = QtCore.QThread()
        self.moveToThread(self.TheWorker)
        self.TheWorker.start()

    def calculateData(self):
        # do some calculations here
        # and fill self.dataForTable
        # or some other variables needed for yout tables
        self.computationFinished.emit() # emit the signal

class TryingStuff(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(TryingStuff, self).__init__(parent)

        # blah blah

        self.table = QtGui.QTableWidget()
        self.setUpTable(self.table)

        # blah blah

        self.worker = MyWorker()
        self.doJob.clicked.connect(self.worker.calculateData)
        self.worker.computationFinished.connect(self.putStuffInA)

    def putStuffInA(self):
        # here use self.worker.dataForTable
        # to fill data for self.table
```

Comment: Thanks. I think I got to that part using a qthread while trying different things earlier. I just can't figure out how to signal the table to update itself.

Comment: Maybe explain more, because I don't see reason why it couldn't work the very same way.

Comment: How do i use self.worker.dataForTable to fill the data for self.table?

Comment: The same way as you did in your example. But now, instead creating list `lista` in `putStuffInA` you use `self.worker.dataForTable`.